# Updating an Azure Block Blob in a datalake without using append while having it under a lease

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have an azure function that writes to a parquet file in a Gen 2 DataLake. It needs to append a parquet record on each execution.

When I try and use an Append Blob, I receive an error that append blobs are not supported with my datalake setup. (Hierarchal Namespace)

My alternative was to obtain a lease on the blob, read the contents out, append my record, then re-upload the blob under the lease and release the lease. However this does not work, because blob client cannot upload blob under a lease. So I risk changes getting overwritten during high volume times.

I need a way to safely edit a block blobs contents without risk of losing or overwriting changes.